# Python - Teradata package cannot connect to ODBC after changing password

Tags: python, odbc, teradata

I have used the teradata package for ~6 months now and have changed my password before without issue. After my most recent password change (via ODBC administrator), I am able to access the server via Teradata SQL Assistant. However, when I attempt to connect in python, I am having the following error:

**Code:**

```
import teradata

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0", logConsole=False)

udaExec.connect(method="odbc", dsn="my_dsn_name_example")
```

**Error Message #1:**

```
DatabaseError: [HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] Loading the Teradata ICU Library Failed. Error is: 126, The driver returned invalid (or failed to return) SQL_DRIVER_ODBC_VER: 03.80
```

- When I explicitly define my username and password in my udaExec.connect function, I get the same error.
- When I enter an intentionally incorrect username and password into udaExec.connect, it gets the same error. Thus, I can conclude that the username and password are not being passed correctly.

I have tried deleting the connection in ODBC administrator, and get the following error code after running my code when the connection is deleted:

**Error Message #2:**

```
DatabaseError: [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

This demonstrates that the teradata package is in fact referencing this ODBC driver, but when I re-add the username and password, I get error message #1 again.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the teradata package, but still receive the same error.

Comment: As part of this, did you change versions of the driver you originally had installed?